# C# error: Use of unassigned local variable

Tags: c#, initialization

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, but shouldn't this code compile, since I'm already checking to see if queue is getting initialized?

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    Byte maxSize;
    Queue queue;

    if(args.Length != 0)
    {
        if(Byte.TryParse(args[0], out maxSize))
            queue = new Queue(){MaxSize = maxSize};
        else
            Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    for(Byte j = 0; j < queue.MaxSize; j++)
        queue.Insert(j);
    for(Byte j = 0; j < queue.MaxSize; j++)
        Console.WriteLine(queue.Remove());
}
```

So if queue is not initialized, then the for loops aren't reachable right? Since the program already terminates with Environment.Exit(0)?

Hope ya'll can give me some pointers :)

Thanks.

Comment: I can't give you any pointers, but I hope you can get a handle on this one.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know that the Environment.Exit() is going to terminate the program; it just sees you executing a static method on a class.  Just initialize `queue` to null when you declare it.

```
Queue queue = null;
```

Answer (score 9):

The compiler doesn't know that Environment.Exit() does not return.  Why not just "return" from Main()?

Comment: I prefer to use Environment.Exit with a non-zero error status in case the program is called from a script.  That way the script can know whether the program was successful or not by checking the exit status.

Comment: Change the return type of main to int and return the status.

Answer (score 8):

A couple of different ways to solve the problem:

Just replace Environment.Exit with return. The compiler knows that return ends the method, but doesn't know that Environment.Exit does.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    if(args.Length != 0) {
       if(Byte.TryParse(args[0], out maxSize))
         queue = new Queue(){MaxSize = maxSize};
       else
         return;
    } else {
       return;   
}
```

Of course, you can really only get away with that because you're using 0 as your exit code in all cases. Really, you should return an int instead of using Environment.Exit. For this particular case, this would be my preferred method

```
static int Main(string[] args) {
    if(args.Length != 0) {
       if(Byte.TryParse(args[0], out maxSize))
         queue = new Queue(){MaxSize = maxSize};
       else
         return 1;
    } else {
       return 2;
    }
}
```

Initialize queue to null, which is really just a compiler trick that says "I'll figure out my own uninitialized variables, thank you very much". It's a useful trick, but I don't like it in this case - you have too many if branches to easily check that you're doing it properly. If you *really* wanted to do it this way, something like this would be clearer:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  Byte maxSize;
  Queue queue = null;

  if(args.Length == 0 || !Byte.TryParse(args[0], out maxSize)) {
     Environment.Exit(0);
  }
  queue = new Queue(){MaxSize = maxSize};

  for(Byte j = 0; j < queue.MaxSize; j++)
    queue.Insert(j);
  for(Byte j = 0; j < queue.MaxSize; j++)
    Console.WriteLine(queue.Remove());
}
```

Add a return statement after Environment.Exit. Again, this is more of a compiler trick - but is slightly more legit IMO because it adds semantics for humans as well (though it'll keep you from that vaunted 100% code coverage)

```
static void Main(String[] args) {
  if(args.Length != 0) {
     if(Byte.TryParse(args[0], out maxSize)) {
        queue = new Queue(){MaxSize = maxSize};
     } else {
        Environment.Exit(0);
        return;
     }
  } else { 
     Environment.Exit(0);
     return;
  }

  for(Byte j = 0; j < queue.MaxSize; j++)
     queue.Insert(j);
  for(Byte j = 0; j < queue.MaxSize; j++)
     Console.WriteLine(queue.Remove());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler only knows that the code is or isn't reachable if you use "return". Think of Environment.Exit() as a function that you call, and the compiler don't know that it will close the application.

Comment: I can think of two other sources of unreachable code:
Break or continue in a loop, and throw :)

Comment: That's true. I was referring to this specific question, but thanks for the clarification, it could lead to some misinterpretation.