# Compiler warning: null reference exception

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I have the following code in Visual Studio 2005.

```
    Dim OutFile As System.IO.StreamWriter
    Try
        OutFile = New System.IO.StreamWriter(Filename)
       // Do stuff with OutFile
    Catch Ex As Exception
       // Handle Exception
    Finally
       If OutFile IsNot Nothing Then OutFile.Close()
    End Try
```

But VS2005 brings up the warning for the line "If OutFile IsNot.." that

> Variable 'OutFile' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.

Is there some way of removing this warning by subtly altering the code or is there just a better way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Dim OutFile As System.IO.StreamWriter
OutFile = Nothing
Try
    OutFile = New System.IO.StreamWriter(Filename)
   // Do stuff with OutFile
Catch Ex As Exception
   // Handle Exception
Finally
   If OutFile IsNot Nothing Then OutFile.Close()
End Try
```

**Similar to [C# error: Use of unassigned local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256073/c-error-use-of-unassigned-local-variable#256078)**

Comment: Nearly, but it pointed me in the right direction. NULL isn't allowed but Outfile = Nothing does the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Just noticed it and fixed it.  I usually program in c# if you couldn't guess.

Comment: :) It's nice to have a warning-less project. Thanks again.

Comment: So we have to use an assignment to avoid the warning...?  Seems pretty stupid, especially because you are assigning it to nothing, which means the same warning should still exists becuase the null reference could still occur.  This is dumb!  VS should not even waste its time trying to figure out if my code is going to give a null reference; there must be a way to disable this warning.

Comment: Not really. It's not trying to prevent the null reference but the accidental omission of a default value. Forcing you to explicitly provide a default to remove the warning makes you aware that you have left the variable potentially undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Its a question of scope, the initialisation of the outfile object is happening in a block of code not visible to the fianlly block.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct, of course, but it doesn't explain why or when explicit initialization may matter.

VB.NET *usually* assigns a default value (`0` or `Nothing`) when a variable is declared, but there are corner cases where it doesn't.

Consider this simple console application:

```
Sub Main()
    For i As Integer = 1 To 5
        Dim number As Integer
        If i = 3 Then number = 3

        Console.Write(number)
    Next
End Sub
```

What's the output look like? You might expect that `number` gets set to `0` for every iteration of the loop, and it only gets set to `3` on the third iteration of the loop. Then for the fourth and fifth iteration, it'd be `0` again. So the output is `00300`, right? Not so. The output of this code is actually

> 00333

That's because in VB.NET, the lifetime of a variable declared in a loop is for the **whole** loop, not for one iteration of the loop (Not what you'd expect, huh?). But if you explicitly set the value of `number` to `0` at its declaration, like so

```
Dim number As Integer = 0
```

then the output looks like

> 00300

So it's *usually* safe to assume VB.NET will set the default value when you `Dim` a variable, but it's always safest to set it explicitly to `0` or `Nothing` to get the expected behavior.