# Why does checking if an object is null cause a warning at compile time?

Tags: .net, vb.net

This project at work has this code in some method:

```
Dim pDataTable As DataTable
Dim pDS As DataSet

pDS = someClass.GetSomeDataSet()

If (pDS.Tables.Count > 0) Then
    pDataTable = pDS.Tables("SomeTableName")
    foo(pDataTable)
EndIf


If (pDataTable IsNot Nothing) Then
    pDataTable.Dispose()
EndIf

pDataTable = Nothing
```

Just curious, but why does `If (pDataTable IsNot Nothing) Then` cause this warning:

> Variable 'pDataTable' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.

I completely understand what it's telling me. If I simply call `pDataTable.Dispose()` and it was never instantiated in the first if block then my application is going to blow up. But why does it generate a warning for simply comparing a value to null?

If I wanted to get rid of this warning, should I just change the declaration of `pDataTable` to also create a new instance of `DataTable`?

Comment: To answer the _why_ question, it's probably because the compiler is not smart enough to recognize that situation.  It simply sees that you are attempting to use a variable that has not been definitely assigned so it issues the warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should set its value to null when you declare it if you're going to use it before you assign it elsewhere:

```
Dim pDataTable As DataTable = Nothing
```

This applies even to the case where you are checking its value, even if you're only checking whether it's null, e.g. via `If (pDataTable IsNot Nothing)`.  Unfortunately, the compiler is not smart enough to realize that you are checking whether its null, hence the warning.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen that in my 3 years of experience. Is that common practice, or more so just "Technically you should but no one does and it's really not a big deal"?

Comment: Look, the point is, a variable needs to have a value before you use it.  If you're going to use it, even if it's in a statement like `If (pDataTable IsNot Nothing)`, then it needs to have a value first.  It doesn't matter if you assign it on the same line you declare it on (like I've shown) or if you do it a few lines later, as long as you assign it before you use it.

Comment: I get that. I was just asking if that's common practice or not, as I've never seen anyone explicitly assign null to an object unless they're getting rid of it. Obviously you need to assign a value to something before using it. I just thought it was strange that null checks cause warnings.

Comment: I can't speak to whether it's common practice except to say that it seems to me it's common practice not to have warnings; if you don't want a warning, then you can set its value to null.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know it's a null check specifically. It's just the first place in the code that `pDataTable` gets queried, and the compiler will notice then that you have only assigned it a value in a partial path of the code. If you change the null check into something else, while still using `pDataTable`, you will still get the warning.

Comment: You would get the same thing with strings if you don't initialize them.

Comment: I was writing an answer as to **why** you might need to explicitly initialize, but then it got closed as a duplicate. So I added the answer to the [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323562/compiler-warning-null-reference-exception) instead, if you're curious.

Comment: Use the `New` keyword to instantiate it or as you have mentioned it to set it to `Nothing`.

Comment: @A.Franklin That's a very interesting example you've provided. Thanks.