# What does assigning variable to null do?

Tags: c#

In the following I get a compile time error that says "Use of unassigned local variable 'match'"
if I just enter string match; but it works when I use string match = null;
So what is the difference and in general, if a string is not being assigned a value right away should I be assigning to null like this?

```
string question = "Why do I need to assign to null";
char[] delim = { ' ' };
string[] strArr = question.Split(delim);
//Throws Error
string match;
//No Error
//string match = null;
foreach (string s in strArr)
 {
    if (s == "Why")
      {
         match = "Why";
      }
 }
Console.WriteLine(match);
```

Comment: The compiler just wants to know you meant it :-)

Comment: Still exist several answers on StackOverflow: just one -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256073/c-sharp-error-use-of-unassigned-local-variable

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C# language prevents the use of a local until it has been definitively assigned a value.  In this example the compiler doesn't understand the semantics of `Split` and has to assume that `strArr` can be an empty collection and hence the body of the loop could potentially not execute.  This means from a definitive assignment perspective the `foreach` doesn't assign `match` a value.  Hence it's still unassigned when you get to `WriteLine`

By changing the declaration to `string match = null` the value is marked as definitely assigned from the very start.  The loop calculation hence doesn't matter

Answer (score 5):

Depends on your scenario, though:

```
string match = null;
```

Or:

```
string match = string.Empty;
```

are both acceptable practices.

In your case it is possible for `match` never to have a value assigned, thus the compiler error.

Answer (score 4):

You are finding the difference between declaration and assignment.  Declaration, with lines like

```
string match;
```

simply *declares* to the compiler that you will be using a variable `match` of type string.  Assignment, with lines like

```
match = null;
```

*assigns* the value `null` to `match`.

It is possible for a language to declare that declaration and assignment must always be separated (I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that old versions of Visual Basic did this), but most languages allow you to combine declaration and assignment, writing

```
string match = null; // combined declaration and assignment
```

to mean

```
string match; // declaration
match = null; // assignment
```

C# requires that variables be assigned before they are used.  Unlike fields and events, local variables aren't automatically assigned default values, so you have to prove to the compiler that, before you use `match`, `match` will have some value.  The compiler doesn't care which value `match` has, as long as that variable is of type string.

In your case, the compiler can't prove with local analysis that `strArr` will be nonempty because the compiler doesn't inspect the code of `Split`, so there is no guarantee that the code will even enter the `foreach` loop, let along meet the condition to assign to `match`.  Since the `Console.WriteLine` call uses `match`, and since `match` may not be assigned at runtime with the `string match` declaration, the compiler requires you to assign `match` outside the loop.  One way to meet the requirement is to use `string match = null` instead of `string match`.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler has realised that there is a chance you can use `match` without it ever being assigned to anything.  The `foreach` loop may never get executed.  So you have declared the variable, but the compiler has realised it can be accessed without ever being assigned, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

You have the if() block in there which would initialize the variable 'match' if the condition is met. In that case, match is an object representing actual block in memory.

However, if the if() condition isn't met, there is no 'else' block that does a default initialization of the 'match' variable, in which case you'll be attempting to access a non-initialized object, which would fail.

you can work around this by:

1. As you commented, default initializing 'match' before the for-loop.
2. Adding a default 'else' condition after the for-loop.

Luckily if you're working on an IDE, it points this out to you as a compile exception.

Answer (score 0):

When you state, `type variable = null;`, you are initializing the variable. If you state `type variable;`, you are only declaring the variable.

Comment: should be 'variable = null' - double == is the equals comparator