# Use of unassigned local variable 'enumerable' with two params

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have define collection of enumerable like this

```
IEnumerable<TaggedEdge<int, float>> enumerable;

if (tryFunc(World.sortedList_3.IndexOfValue(vector2), ref enumerable) && World.gclass19_0.bool_1)
{
}
```

And here I am getting error for

> Use of unassigned local variable 'enumerable'. Error code : CS0165

So here how can I solve this one ? Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Use of unassigned local variable" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710485/what-does-use-of-unassigned-local-variable-mean)

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256073/c-sharp-error-use-of-unassigned-local-variable

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233000/why-compile-error-use-of-unassigned-local-variable

Comment: You probably need an out parameter instead of a ref parameter

Comment: ... or assign `null` to it.

Comment: Yes I know that if I assign an local variable and don't use it then it will give me that error but here I have assign two data types so here how to pass null value to enumerable. So my question is exactly for that purpose that how to mention two values for int and float to enumerable.

Comment: @hardikdhankecha It's not a warning that you're not using a variable, it's an error that you are using a variable which value may not have been set yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is to initialize a new enumrable:

```
// IEnumerable is now assigned
    IEnumerable<TaggedEdge<int, float>> enumerable = new IEnumerable<TaggedEdge<int, float>>();

    if (tryFunc(World.sortedList_3.IndexOfValue(vector2), ref enumerable) && World.gclass19_0.bool_1)
    {
    }
```

Or use `out`:

```
IEnumerable<TaggedEdge<int, float>> enumerable;

if (tryFunc(World.sortedList_3.IndexOfValue(vector2), out enumerable) && World.gclass19_0.bool_1)
{
}
```

`out` means:

*means the parameter will be initialized in the method before it returns*

`ref` means:

*the parameted will be initialzed **outside** of the method.*

Comment: I think "the parameted will be initialzed outside of the method" is a poor definition of what `ref` means.

Comment: How is this possible `new IEnumerable<TaggedEdge<int, float>>();`

Comment: @Enigmativityprobably, but that's not the point of the question at hand.

Comment: @EmrahSüngü this is pasudo to try and show him the point, it is not, but the question here is regarding what it means unassigned.

Comment: No its not possible to assign new IEnumerable<TaggedEdge<int, float>>();

when I am assigning its showing me "Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface"

If I am mentioning Out with enumerable then its working fine.